# Log4j on weblogic10 only logs to console

Tags: log4j, weblogic-10.x, rollingfileappender

I'm trying to print my log messages to a file. At this point, it only logs to the console which is not ideal for future support.

My log4j.properties file looks like this:

log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, stdout, logfile

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - <%m>%n

log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.logfile.File:/apps/wlserver10/bpdomain/servers/HRServer/logs/HRServer.log
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxFileSize=4MB
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.logfile.Append=true
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - %m%n

This works fine on my local weblogic instance, but when I try to deploy it to the server it doesn't write the log file.

Can anyone please help me find why?
Thanks in advance
Yols

Answer (score 1):

Is it the missing `=` after File instead of `:` ?

log4j.appender.logfile.File:/apps/wlserver10/bpdomain/servers/HRServer/logs/HRServer.log

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss '=' in this part of your configuration:

log4j.appender.logfile.File**:/**apps/wlserver10/bpdomain/servers/HRServer/logs/HRServer.log

Regards